# What is the correct pronunciation of 'Sabriel'?

Tags: old-kingdom

Spoilers ahead for '[Terciel & Elinor](http://www.garthnix.com/books/the-old-kingdom/terciel-elinor/)' and the wider '[Old Kingdom](http://www.garthnix.com/books/the-old-kingdom/)' series...

I've just finished listening to the audiobook version of 'Terciel & Elinor' by [Garth Nix](http://www.garthnix.com/about/), the 6th part of the 'Old Kingdom' series.

At the end of the book Sabriel is mentioned (the daughter of Terciel & Elinor). In the audiobook (narrated by [Billie Fulford-Brown](https://www.billiefulfordbrown.com/)) she pronounces Sabriel as Say-Brie-El.

In the original three books (narrated by [Tim Curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Curry)) he pronounces Sabriel as 'Sab-Brie-El'.

For me, Tim Curry's pronunciation will always be the correct one, but, the *new* pronunciation is different - is it correct or just a slip-up on the part of the narrator?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is answered in [the FAQ on Garth Nix's website](http://www.garthnix.com/faqs/) by the author himself - basically, both pronunciations are correct:

> Q. How do you pronounce Sabriel, Lirael and Ancelstierre?
>
> I always say you can pronounce the names however you like. I sometimes change how I pronounce them myself. However:
>
> Sabriel SAB-ree-ELLE or SAY-bree-ELLE
> Lirael LI-ray-ELLE (with the ‘Li’ as in ‘lift’)
> Ancelstierre AN-sell-stee-AIR
> Clayr Like ‘Air”
> Clariel KLA-ree-ELLE

As you can see, Sabriel can be pronounced in both ways (either rhyming with Gabriel or with Gabrielle).

Comment: Similar question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/216729/how-do-you-pronounce-hain/