How should I pronounce Jalabhar Xho’s last name?
In George R.R. Martin’s A Song of Ice and Fire series, there is a somewhat exotic character called Jalabhar Xho:

JALABHAR XHO, an exile prince from the Summer Isles

I’m not sure how to pronounce this character’s last name: “Xho”.
A few reasonable guesses for the ⟨xh⟩ digraph include:
/k/, /ks/, /ksh/, /ʃ/, /gz/, /ʒ/, /dʒ/, /h/, /x/, /χ/, /kǁʰ/, /ᵏǁʰ/, ∅
But, as I’m not sure which language(s) inspired the Summer Tongue, it’s unclear which (if any) of these guesses are correct.
Are there any clues as to how George intended this name to be pronounced?

relevant: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/216729/how-do-you-pronounce-hain/216736#216736 - you always have "reader's rights".

My immediate suspicion is that you should pronounce it the way you would say the beginning of Xhosa. The Summer Isles, if I recall correctly, are the closest, most developed part of Sothoryos, so they're part of the Africa analogue—probably the only analogous groups, since the actual landmass of Sothoryos fits the "Darkest Africa" stereotype to the extent that the Sothoryi are allegedly not even humans. So the odds are good that Xho is directly from the word Xhosa.
